# Audio and Lock-Screen hotkeys broken on Zesty

Tags: shortcut-keys, 17.04

After system updates this morning, a number of hotkeys are not working on my laptop running 17.04 Zesty:

- KeePass Auto-Type (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)
- Lock screen (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)
- Launch terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
- Launch calculator (media keys)
- Volume up/down/mute (media keys)

That may not be an exhaustive list - there are probably things I haven't found.  Other hotkeys are still working fine, such as:

- Window controls (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+arrow keys)
- Workspace controls (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+arrow keys)
- Switch windows (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) or switch applications (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>)

I find entries for both working key combinations and broken ones in my "Keyboard" control panel:

[image: screenshot of Keyboard control panel]

Here are the packages that were installed or upgraded this morning:

```
2017-08-28 08:30:26 install linux-image-4.10.0-33-generic:amd64 <none> 4.10.0-33.37
2017-08-28 08:30:28 install linux-image-extra-4.10.0-33-generic:amd64 <none> 4.10.0-33.37
2017-08-28 08:30:32 install linux-headers-4.10.0-33:all <none> 4.10.0-33.37
2017-08-28 08:30:37 install linux-headers-4.10.0-33-generic:amd64 <none> 4.10.0-33.37
2017-08-28 08:30:40 install linux-tools-4.10.0-33:amd64 <none> 4.10.0-33.37
2017-08-28 08:30:40 install linux-tools-4.10.0-33-generic:amd64 <none> 4.10.0-33.37
2017-08-28 08:30:16 upgrade google-chrome-stable:amd64 60.0.3112.101-1 60.0.3112.113-1
2017-08-28 08:30:22 upgrade ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 1:0.4.22 1:0.4.22.1
2017-08-28 08:30:22 upgrade logrotate:amd64 3.8.7-2ubuntu3 3.8.7-2ubuntu3.1
2017-08-28 08:30:22 upgrade heroku:amd64 6.13.18-1 6.13.19-1
2017-08-28 08:30:26 upgrade linux-image-extra-virtual:amd64 4.10.0.32.32 4.10.0.33.33
2017-08-28 08:30:31 upgrade linux-generic:amd64 4.10.0.32.32 4.10.0.33.33
2017-08-28 08:30:32 upgrade linux-image-generic:amd64 4.10.0.32.32 4.10.0.33.33
2017-08-28 08:30:39 upgrade linux-headers-generic:amd64 4.10.0.32.32 4.10.0.33.33
2017-08-28 08:30:39 upgrade linux-libc-dev:amd64 4.10.0-32.36 4.10.0-33.37
2017-08-28 08:30:40 upgrade linux-tools-common:all 4.10.0-32.36 4.10.0-33.37
2017-08-28 08:30:40 upgrade linux-tools-virtual:amd64 4.10.0.32.32 4.10.0.33.33
2017-08-28 08:30:41 upgrade intel-microcode:amd64 3.20170511.1~ubuntu17.04.0 3.20170707.1~ubuntu17.04.0
```

Is there a known issue in one of these updates?  And what is my best path back to working hotkeys?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything resolved itself after a couple of updates.  If this was a regression it's been fixed.